# Atualizar o texto de um Toast sem esperar que ele suma

Tags: android

Estou criando um aplicativo para testes e estou usando *toasts* para validar meus testes. Eu normalmente defino um toast da seguinte maneira:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Texto que eu quero que apareça",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Existe alguma maneira de alterar o texto de um *toast* enquanto ele ainda está sendo exibido?

Quando eu tento simplesmente mandar um outro *toast* ser exibido, o primeiro *toast* precisa antes desaparecer para que o outro apareça, gostaria de saber como mudar isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acordo com a referência: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html.

O método estático makeText retorna o Objeto Toast criado, acredito que se você  guardar a referência para o objeto e usar o método setText a tempo de ele ainda estar visível, o texto é alterado. Caso não funcione, você pode cancelar (instâneamente) o Toast, com o método cancel, e gerar um novo com o novo texto.

**Exemplo de código:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Toast mToast;

    public void showToast(String text) {
        if (mToast == null) {
            mToast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        mToast.setText(text);
        mToast.cancel();
        mToast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo de como definir o toast sem ser estaticamente? Tentei mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Você poderia guardar ele como uma variável local da sua classe (Activity ou Fragment) e reutilizar ela. O exemplo abaixo é mais genérico, pois não da pra saber se o toast ainda está visível.

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Toast mToast;

    public void showToast(String text) {
        if(mToast == null) {
            mToast = Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        mToast.setText(text);
        mToast.cancel();
        mToast.show();
    }
}
Ou você pode usar a library SuperToast (https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts), que é bem versátil.

Comment: @Wakim Seria bom você editar a sua resposta pra incluir o código do seu último comentário. A resposta fica melhor (e potencialmente mais útil), e o código mais legível. :)